# Switch Case Statement C++ Coding Style

Tags: c++, coding-style

I use an enum to switch between types in a type system like:

```
enum FruitType {
    APPLE;
    PEAR;
    CHERRY;
    ORANGE;
    BANANA;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Now I several functions which are only valid for a subset (varies between the functions) and should throw an exception for all others.
This might be a matter of personal taste, but which of the following would you consider most-easy-to-read / maintainable / least-error-prone? 
Or is there even a more elegant version I couldn't think of?

Option 1:

```
switch(o.fruitType)
{
    case APPLE:
    case PEAR:
    case ORANGE:
    {
        // do all the stuff i want to do
        string ret;
        // ...
        function(o,ret);
        return ret;     
    }
    default:
        throw InvalidFunctionParameterException();
}
```

Option 2:

```
if(o.fruitType == APPLE || o.fruitType == PEAR || o.fruitType == ORANGE)
{
    // do all the stuff i want to do
    string ret;
    // ...
    function(o,ret);
    return ret;     
}
else
{
    throw InvalidFunctionParameterException();
}
```

Option 3:

```
switch(o.fruitType)
{
    case APPLE:
    case PEAR:
    case ORANGE:
        break;
    default:
        throw InvalidFunctionParameterException();
}

// do all the stuff i want to do
string ret;
// ...
function(o,ret);
return ret;
```

Comment: This seems to belong on CodeReview : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: switch case is efficient then if option 1 is good

Answer (score 2):

I agree, that this is a personal matter, but I believe, that first option is the most readable.

I'm also using it in situations, when function should react for some values, but also **explicitly shouldn't react for others**:

```
switch(o.fruitType)
{
    case APPLE:
    {
        DoSomethingWithApple();
        break;
    }
    case PEAR:
    {
        DoSomethingWithPear();
        break;
    }
    case ORANGE:
    {
        DoSomethingWithOrange();
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        // Explicitly left empty
    }
}
```

I leave this "`Explicitly left empty`" comment, such that future readers of my code will know, that I explicitly wanted that piece of code to do nothing if other value is encountered. And optimizer will cut this code out, so it won't affect performance.

Answer (score 1):

Programming style. It's very personal, and everyone has their own opinion.

I find it's best to try to do  "What expresses what I mean best". In other words, Which way of writing this represents the flow that you expect, and the behaviour that you'd expect, based on "This is what I want to have happen" (for example the requirement specification that tells you what the code should do).

I personally find the third one the hardest to read, since it relies on you spotting the `throw` in the middle of the `switch` as key. If you put the other "do stuff" functionality in `switch` (or `if`), it's clearer that "We do this for these things, and anything else is an error".

I expect that the compiler will generate more or less equivalent code in the end, possibly with slightly better code for the `switch` than the `if`, since `switch` is often solved with a table, where the `if` more or less have to follow what you have written (with the short circuit of conditions being an important characteristic here).

Of course, you also have to take into account the project/company coding style guides, which may have something to say about "how to write switch statements".

Answer (score 1):

> Or is there even a more elegant version I couldn't think of?

Implement it as a class hierarchy with a virtual function:

```
// client code:
o.processByFruitType();

class Fruit {
    virtual string processByFruitType() {
        throw InvalidFunctionParameterException();
    }
};

// fruit implementations:
class Apple: public Fruit {
    virtual string processByFruitType() override {
        // do all the stuff i want to do
        string ret;
        // ...
        function(*this,ret);
        return ret;     
    }
};
```

Other specializations follow a similar implementation.

Comment: As things stand you're going to have to duplicate that "all the stuff" code in `Pear` and `Orange`. I think a further abstraction is needed. It's not clear what that should be, though, because from a fake example I can't tell whether the difference between processable and non-processable fruit can cleanly be expressed by inheritance.

Comment: There are several reasons why I do not use virtual functions here, the most important being that the functions do not semantically belong to the objects as members

Answer (score -1):

> Or is there even a more elegant version I couldn't think of?

If you do this a significant amount in your code then write a function/macro supporting assertions like this:

```
PARAM_ASSERT(o.fruitType == APPLE || o.fruitType == PEAR || o.fruitType == ORANGE);

// do all the stuff i want to do
string ret;
// ...
function(o,ret);
return ret;
```

The implementation might be vaguely like:

```
#define PARAM_ASSERT(X) \
    do { \
        if (!(X)) throw InvalidFunctionParameterException(); \
    } while (false)
```

Using a macro, you preserve the freedom to enrich the exceptions with `__LINE__`, `__FILE__`, `#X` (a stringified version of the condition) etc. later without touching the client code....

Comment: This is better coding style?

Comment: @olevegard: Yes, in my opinion it is.  Concision and consistency is an important part of a robust, productive development environment - and a precondition check is a familiar notion to most professional programmers, so nothing here will surprise them.  Note especially that the question isn't about the typical "do this for some enumerations but something else for others", though that's very visible the real task is very specifically validation of function parameters.

Comment: I think, that it is a lot less readable than three options presented by OP. Also, macros are evil. Even if you want to introduce PARAM_ASSERT, you might have done it genericly (even better, as a static method of some Assert class to maintain nice OOP)

Comment: @Spook: You're welcome to your opinion of course.  Macros may be evil, but a few macros for things like assertions and logging are worthwhile on balance for their ability to inject __LINE__, __FILE__, stringified arguments etc. without programmer effort or obfuscating verbosity.

Comment: @TonyD Well I guess coding style is mostly a matter of opinion. Myself I stay away from macros as much as I can. I find them hard to read and they often have less descriptive names.Event though it makes it possible to put the sanity check on one line, it means you have to wrtie the whole `o.fruitType == APPLE || o.fruitType == PEAR || o.fruitType == ORANGE` thing. And you'd probably end up using a switch to handle the other options anyways...

Comment: @TonyD And apart from what I already said, what if that enum has 20 values and function works correctly for 18 of them? I can't imagine writing an extremely long sanity check using macro being more readable by simple switch/case with exception in default...

Comment: @TonyD, I'd rather write: `if (!(o.fruitType == APPLE || o.fruitType == PEAR || o.fruitType == ORANGE)) throw InvalidFunctionParameterException();` but even that's ... not good coding style. If you avoid the macro, at the very least you will be looking at the same code as the compiler when you try to understand the code or the code's weird behavior.